# Is there a specific mime type for storing AES encrypted files?

Tags: file, encryption, aes, mime-types

I have tried using `application/octet-stream` to store an encrypted file, (encryption was in aes) at the end I realized that I could successfully decrypt that file to it's original format if and only if it was a media file (such as video, audio , picture ) but if the encrypted file was originally a document file (such as PDF, doc, txt , even html) the decryption process fails.

I have also tried using `*/*` as mime type this made the operating system (Android in my case ) to recognize it as a folder.

Uptil now am still looking for a way to perfectly store encrypted files with appropriate mime type so that they can be successfully decrypted to any original format.

Comment: *"Is there a specific mime type for storing AES encrypted files?"* - No, AES produces bytes and every filesystem is capable of handling binary data such as AES encrypted files. This has nothing to do with mime types. Perhaps this is a Android specific limitation.

Comment: But to create a file in Android I need to specify the mine type am using the ```Document.createFile()``` method of Android extension library under SAF. if I don't specify mimetype the file creation process fails.